# Refactoring jQuery repeating pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, refactoring, toggle

I have painted my self into a corner in order to quickly prototype.
What's the best way to refactor the following jQuery code? Its functionality is to toggle between some sidebar navigation items. I need it to be more dynamic in order to be scalable.

Would you add the IDs inside the if statements, in an array and iterate through them? Use variables? Create a function and call it on the html side onClick? No matter what I think of, it stills leads to a bunch of repeating code.

Thank you!

```js
// TOGGLING LEFT NAVIGATION
   $('#settingsClick').click(function() {
      if( $('#addContainer, #noteContainer, #logoContainer, #themeContainer').is(':visible') ) {
         $('#addContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#noteContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#logoContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#settingsContainer').slideDown(350);
         $('#themeContainer').slideUp(350);
      } else {
         $('#settingsContainer').slideToggle(350);
      }
   });

   $('#addClick').click(function() {
      if( $('#settingsContainer, #noteContainer, #logoContainer, #themeContainer').is(':visible') ) {
         $('#settingsContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#noteContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#logoContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#addContainer').slideDown(350);
         $('#themeContainer').slideUp(350);
      } else {
         $('#addContainer').slideToggle(350);
      }
   });

   $('#noteClick').click(function() {
      if( $('#settingsContainer, #addContainer, #logoContainer, #themeContainer').is(':visible') ) {
         $('#settingsContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#addContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#logoContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#noteContainer').slideDown(350);
         $('#themeContainer').slideUp(350);
      } else {
         $('#noteContainer').slideToggle(350);
      }
   });

   $('#logoClick').click(function() {
      if( $('#settingsContainer, #addContainer, #noteContainer, #themeContainer').is(':visible') ) {
         $('#settingsContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#addContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#noteContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#logoContainer').slideDown(350);
         $('#themeContainer').slideUp(350);
      } else {
         $('#logoContainer').slideToggle(350);
      }
   });

   $('#themeClick').click(function() {
      if( $('#settingsContainer, #addContainer, #noteContainer, #logoContainer').is(':visible') ) {
         $('#settingsContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#addContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#noteContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#logoContainer').slideUp(350);
         $('#themeContainer').slideDown(350);
      } else {
         $('#themeContainer').slideToggle(350);
      }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="settingsClick">Click Me</a><br>
<div id="settingsContainer">Content...</div>

<br><br>

<a id="addClick">Click Me</a><br>
<div id="addContainer">Content...</div>

<br><br>

<p> Etc... Etc....</p>
```

Comment: Satpal, you beat me to it. Sample html is up now.

Comment: Yes I have access to the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group using the common CSS class, i.e. `header` and `content`. Using the established relationship you can target the others content holder and content associated with the current clicked header element.

```js
$('.container .header').on('click', function() {
  //Get the current element
  var $this = $(this);

  //find the content
  var $content = $this.closest('.container').find('.content'); //$this.next()

  //get all contents
  var content = $('.container .content');

  //Slide up others 
  content.not($content).slideUp(350);

  //Slide down
  $content.slideToggle(350);
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header" id="settingsClick">Click Me</div>
  <div class="content" id="settingsContainer">Content...</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header" id="addClick">Click Me</div>
  <div class="content" id="addContainer">Content...</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header" id="noteClick">Click Me</div>
  <div class="content" id="noteContainer">Content...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Satpal!

Answer (score 1):

the best bet would be to do it like so

```js
$(document).on('click', ".trigger", function() {
  var sibling_content = $(this).siblings(".content");
  if (!sibling_content.hasClass('active')) {
    $(".content").slideUp('slow').removeClass('active');
    sibling_content.slideDown('slow').addClass('active');
  } else {
    sibling_content.slideUp('slow').removeClass('active');
  }
})
```

```css
.trigger {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="trigger">trigger</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="trigger">trigger</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="trigger">trigger</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="trigger">trigger</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great Immortal Dude. Thank you.